# Does GraphicsMagick have inline image crop?

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

ImageMagick has got [Inline Image Crop](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php). Is this also available in GraphicsMagick?

E.g., how can I make the following work?

```
> gm montage -tile 2x1 logo:[20x20+50+50] logo: out.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in GraphicsMagick, see [feature request #52](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/feature-requests/52/).